# Chrome to switch proxy easily under Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, proxy

I know the answer might be no, but would there be any easy way to switch proxy for Chrome under Linux? Ultimately, I want certain sites to use proxy while certain other sites don't, at the same time.

I have even tried to launch Chrome from command line using a different profile, but found (by checking its IP) it is still using the previous proxy .

I know the answer might be no, but feel it wouldn't hurt to ask and confirm. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the sites that should be accessed without a proxy to the proxy exception list. That means the sites on the list will be accessed directly, while all other sites will be accesses through your proxy.

You can also specify the exception line with the `--proxy-bypass-list` option.

If that is not flexible enough for you, you can use the `--proxy-pac-url` to specify the URL for a JavaScript function that determines what kind of connection should be used. With this function you can even specify different proxies for different sites.

For [details on both options see here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings)

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** Ultimately, I want certain sites to use proxy while certain other sites don't, at the same time.

**A:** you can use the `--proxy-pac-url` to specify the URL for a JavaScript function that determines what kind of connection should be used.

That's the road I went down, as per the recommendation, however, only after I've completed written my PAC JavaScript function, did I realized that I asked the wrong question -- not only I need to go through proxy for a handful of certain sites, but I need to fight for their DNS pollution too. I.e. I can't allow Chrome to inquire & cache DNS on it own.

For anyone who is in my same situation, the solution I found is https://github.com/Dreamacro/clash/.